# Probability of a baby being born from midnight to 5 A.M.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Problem**
Suppose we want to know the probability that a child at a hospital is born at a certain time. Let X be the exact time a randomly selected child is born. Assume all births are equally likely to be anytime in 24 hours. Let X = 0 represent midnight, X = 6 is 6:00am, X = 13.5 is 1:30pm, etc.

What is the probability of being born between midnight and 5 am? Round to TWO decimal places.

**Attempt**
I tried to identify the type of distribution this was first of all: it seemed like a continuous distribution type, and I narrowed it down to **Uniform Distribution** (correct me if I'm wrong) since the problem notes that births are all equally likely within the span of 24 hours. I took a look at **Exponential Distribution**, but it requires a rate in the formula and I couldn't calculate one given the information above.

If my setup is correct, then I proceed with the formula: $\int_0^5\frac{1}{24}dx$. I get $\frac{1}{24}$ from the Density Function $\frac{1}{b-a}$, where my maximum and minimum values are **24** and **0**. Is this correct?

Comment: No you do not get 1/24 . You get (5-0) *1/24=5/24. It is easier to do it in your head without integration or even algebra...

Comment: Correct integral – wrong answer? $\frac5{24}$

Comment: So far so good (almost); It IS a uniform distribution for the reason you explained, no need to justify discarding Exponential distribution. Then, you got to the integral - which is correct; but the value of the integral is 5/24, which you must compute to two decimal places.

Comment: Your attempt seems correct. Intuitively, we would expect the answer to be $\frac{5}{24}$ since we are looking at $5$ out of $24$ hours and the time of birth is equally likely throughout the day. We see that $\int_0^5 \frac{1}{24} = \frac{1}{24}x |_0^5 = \frac{5}{24}$.

Comment: @benguin - are you sure that equals 1/5??

Comment: That was a typo (albeit an embarrassing one) on my end, I had edited my comment.

Comment: Are you freaking kidding me?  Midnight to 5 is 5 hours.  There are 24 hours in a day so midnight to 5 represent 5/24 of a day.  If all times are equally likely 5/24 of the babies are born midnight to 5 and probability is 5/24.  If you do it formally you integrate 1/24 to get $x*1/24$ evaluated from 5 to 0.  Or 5/24 - 0/24=5/24.

Comment: @fleablood The question was more of verifying whether or not my distributive property was correctly selected and my setup was fine. There's no need to be rude. Either way, thank you for helping me find the answer to my question.

Comment: Your reasoning is very correct. Except you didn't finish it. $\int_0^5 1/24 dx = 1/24*x|_0^5 = 5/24$. Knowing what the answer has to be should help you when you don't get the answer

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for your candid answer! All of you definitely helped in the end.,

Comment: 5/24 = 0.21 - to give the answer rounded as the question wants